# ¿Como usar Ruby 2.2 en OpenSuse 42.3?

Tags: linux, ruby

Hola necesito usar la biblioteca tk de Ruby, pero la edición por omisión de Opensuse es Ruby 2.1, usé yast para instalar la biblioteca pero me instalo tk para Ruby 2.2 junto a la misma edición.

Ahora tengo dos ediciones de Ruby (2.1 y 2.2), pero la terminal solo usa la 2.1, y cuando quiero "correr" código con tk me señala error pues usa la 2.1, intenté desintalar la 2.1 pero me dice que es la base para muchas aplicaciones, libreoffice entre ellas.

Para "correr" los scripts uso el comando "ruby file.rb", intente usar ruby2_2, ruby2.2, ruby22 en lugar de "ruby" y ninguno funciona, revisé el yast y sí tengo la versión 2.2 pero no sé como usarla.
¿Cómo puedo usar Ruby 2.2?

Comment: Podrías probar instalando [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) o [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout) con las cuales es mucho más fácil gestionar versiones de ruby que las que normalmente vienen instaladas en los distintos sabores de linux

Comment: porque opensuse usa ubuntu